# How to migrate wordpress w from Amazon AWS lightsail instance to hostgator host

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I want to know how I can migrate my WordPress website from Amazon AWS lightsail instance to HostGator host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can migrate your WordPress site manually

1. Choose a New WordPress Host.
2. Back Up Your Site's Files.
3. Back Up Your WordPress Database.
4. Export Your WordPress Database.
5. Create a New SQL Database and Import the Contents of Your Old One.
6. Upload Your Site's Files to the New Web Host.

For more detail please read the following article.

- https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-transfer-your-website-to-hostgator
- https://wpengine.com/resources/migrate-wordpress-site/